# Passing a HTML DOM Property In an input

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i have a simple input and and a paragraph below i want to pass an HTML DOM property like "document.readyState" and get the value inside the `<p>` tag below the input 
this is the code i did it

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" onkeyup="affiche(this.value)">
<p id="message"></p>
<script>
function affiche(b) {
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = b ;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

it doesn't work because the input field return it as string.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" onkeyup="affiche(this.value)">
<p id="message"></p>
<script>
function affiche(b) {
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = document.readyState ;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

it works like that but i want to : everytime i put a text in the input field it shows me value inside the `<p>` tag

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show an example of your desired output, because it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. The value from the input is not used in the second version of your `affiche()` function, so whenever the user types anything the message paragraph will be updated to show just the current `document.readyState` - which is itself going to stay at "complete". Are you trying to update the paragraph to display the value from the input *and* the `document.readyState`?

Comment: **Both solutions work:** In the first code snippet, you take the value of the input (it's a string) and put it into the paragraph (which is a string). There isn't even type conversion necessary.

Comment: @nnnnnn : i want the word 'complete' to be showed in the first example.
i want whatever 'document.?' i type in the input it shows me its value below

Comment: no, i type the word 'document.readyState' what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, but in your comment:

> i want whatever 'document.?' i type in the input it shows me its value below

...you seem to be saying that you want the user to be able to enter the name of a `document` property into the input and then have the value of that property be displayed in the paragraph element. So if they type in "readyState" then the paragraph will display "complete". If so, the following code will do it:

```
function affiche(propName) {
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = document[propName];
}
```

Note that if the user types a value that isn't a valid property then the string "undefined" will be displayed.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fevnsamr/

**Update**:

> when i type 'readyState' it shows me the value and when i type 'document.readyState' it doesn't?

The only practical way to evaluate *any* object property that is entered is with the [`eval()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```
function affiche(propName) {
  var p = document.getElementById("message");
  try {
    p.innerHTML = eval(propName);
  } catch(e) {
    p.innerHTML = "invalid";
  }
}
```

I've added a try/catch because the user may type something that gives a syntax error when evaluated.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fevnsamr/2/

Note: To everybody now tempted to comment that "`eval()` is evil" - no it isn't, it's just a tool. Almost always the wrong tool for the job, but it's the only practical option here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but why when i type 'readyState' it shows me the value and when i type 'document.readyState' it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

```js
      var ipt = $('#ipt');
      var ptxt = $('#ptxt');

      function render(){
        var txt = ipt.val();
        ptxt.text(txt);
      }

      ipt.on('keyup',function(){
        render();
      });

      render();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ipt"/>
<p id="ptxt"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example using `Function`.

```js
function affiche(b) {
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = new Function('return ' + b)();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="affiche(this.value)" value="document.readyState" autofocus='' />
<p id="message"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run arbitrary code entered by the user, you will need `eval` or equivalent.

But if you only need property lookups, you can use

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function() {
  var p = document.getElementById("message");
  try {
    p.textContent = this.value.split('.').reduce(function(obj, prop) {
      return obj[prop];
    }, window) + '';
  } catch(e) {
    p.innerHTML = '<span class="error">Invalid</span>';
  }
});
```

```css
.error { color: red; }
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<p id="message"></p>
```